# How to enable SharePoint Online External Access Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We want to programatically enable external user access to a list item in a SharePoint Online List/ Library. This should allow us to pass an individual user email address and allow external access to that user account.

As per my understanding, it doesn't expose any API to enable external user access using a programmatic method and appreciate any support.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an anonymous link using the `CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument` PnP CSOM extension method as below and then share the document with external user:

```
string link = context.Web.CreateAnonymousLinkForDocument("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/Documents/sample.docx",ExternalSharingDocumentOption.View);
```

Or you can also use the `UpdateDocumentSharingInfo` method to share documents with external users as below:

```
var userRoles = new List<UserRoleAssignment>();
var users = new List<string>() { "user.name@outlook.com", "user.name@domain.com" };
foreach (var user in users)
{
    UserRoleAssignment role = new UserRoleAssignment();
    role.UserId = user;
    role.Role = Role.Edit;
    userRoles.Add(role);
}
string message = "Please accept this invite to access the document.";

string fileUrl = "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Documents/Document.docx";
DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo(context, fileUrl, userRoles, true, true, true, message, true, true);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

References -

[External sharing API for SharePoint and OneDrive for Business](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/10/02/external-sharing-api-for-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business/)

[Invite external users to SharePoint site using CSOM](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2016/09/invite-external-users-to-sharepoint-csom.html)

PnP Github Sample - [Core.ExternalSharing](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.ExternalSharing)